# updating a unicode file gives me chinese characters

Tags: windows, perl, unicode, 64-bit

I have an "Application.config" file, which a Unicode (as opposed to ANSI or UTF8) file, which contains something like

```
...
<GENERAL>
            ...
    <FULLVERSION>18.0.13.227</FULLVERSION>
</GENERAL>
...
```

The following script is supposed to change that to 18.1.00.012, and did on 32-bit Perl/OS:

```
my ($Company, $Config);

$Company=$ENV{ProgramData}."\\Sage\\Accounts\\2012\\Application.config";
if( -f  $Company)
{
  $Config='';
  if(open(APPCONF, "<".$Company))
  {
    while(<APPCONF>)
    {
      $Config.=$_;
    }
    close(APPCONF);
  }
  if($Config=~s/(<.F.U.L.L.V.E.R.S.I.O.N.>.).*?(<.\/.F.U.L.L.V.E.R.S.I.O.N.>.)/\1\xfa\2/mi)
  {
    $Config=~s/\xfa/1\x008\x00\.\x000\x001\.\x000\x000\x00\.\x000\x001\x002\x00/mi;
    if(open(APPCONF, ">".$Company))
    {
      binmode(APPCONF);
      print APPCONF $Config;
      close APPCONF;
    }
  }
}
```

What happens (on 64-bit Perl) is "FULLVERSION" looks OK but "/FULLVERSION" has been completely mangled and looks like chinese.

Can anyone help?

Pete

Comment: What encoding does the file have? Unicode is not an encoding, Unicode can be represented by several different encodings (UTF-8, UTF-16, UTF-32).

Comment: It is 2 bytes per character, I think. (Don't give me that look, I didn't create the file). The point being missed here is that I have inherited some code that worked on 32-bit but does not work on 64-bit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
use autodie qw(:all);
use IO::File qw();
require File::BOM;
my $Company = $ENV{ProgramData} . "\\Sage\\Accounts\\2012\\Application.config";

# File::Slurp apparently is buggy with PerlIO, no time to investigate.
# Let's read/write files the normal way.
my $Config = do {
    open my $appconf, '<:via(File::BOM)', $Company;
    join q(), $appconf->getlines;
};

$Config =~ s|
    (?<= <FULLVERSION> )
    .*
    (?= </FULLVERSION> )
    |18.1.0.012|msx;

{
    open my $appconf, '>:encoding(UTF-16LE):via(File::BOM)', $Company;
    $appconf->print($Config);
}
```

---

Better yet, do not mangle XML with regex, use an [XML module](http://p3rl.org/XML%3a%3aLibXML) instead. They also understand UTF-16.

---

---

---

hexdump **Application.bad_2.config**

```
0000:0170 | 09 00 3C 00  46 00 55 00  4C 00 4C 00  56 00 45 00 | ..<.F.U.L.L.V.E.
0000:0180 | 52 00 53 00  49 00 4F 00  4E 00 3E 00  31 00 38 00 | R.S.I.O.N.>.1.8.
0000:0190 | 2E 00 30 00  31 2E 00 30  00 30 00 2E  00 30 00 31 | ..0.1..0.0...0.1
0000:01A0 | 00 32 00 3C  00 2F 00 46  00 55 00 4C  00 4C 00 56 | .2.<./.F.U.L.L.V
0000:01B0 | 00 45 00 52  00 53 00 49  00 4F 00 4E  00 3E 00 0D | .E.R.S.I.O.N.>..
0000:01C0 | 00 0A 00 09  00 3C 00 2F  00 47 00 45  00 4E 00 45 | .....<./.G.E.N.E
```

Answer (score 2):

Observe that you inserted an odd number of bytes. This shifts all the bytes and makes low bytes become high bytes and vice versa. In particular, at offset 0x0194 you have `31 2E 00` instead of `31 00 2E 00`.

Comment: Thankyou. Of course, - I simply could not see that without help.